# How to decline minutes

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Have I understood this correctly?

четырнадцать часов однa минут

четырнадцать часов две минуты

четырнадцать часов три минуты

:

четырнадцать часов пять минут

Comment: одна минута, the rest is fine. It's also worth mentioning ноль минут, but I don't think you encounter that in colloquial speech.

Comment: Keep in mind that any number ending on "один/одна/одно" (when spoken) requires the noun to be in singular nominative.  So, 14:31 would be "четырнадцать часов тридцать одна минут**а**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments, the only mistake is "одна минут". The correct phrase is:
четырнадцать часов однa минут**а**

Answer (score 5):

- 1 мину**та**
- 2,3,4 мину**ты**
- 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 мину**т**
- 11-19 мину**т**
- numbers ending with 0 (zero): 0, 10, 20... мину**т**
- Others depend on the last digit according to first 3 rules (2**1** мину**та**, 3**2** мину**ты**, 4**5** мину**т**)

Comment: В списке отутствует  "10 мину**т**"